# Is there a JSR-303-validating Filter implementation for Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-integration

Before I go off reinventing the wheel, is there a Filter implementation in Spring Integration for JSR-303 validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a public one but I do recall someone building some support for JSR 303 in SI at their Company; if you come up with something reusable, you might consider contributing it to the extension repo.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions